# What are the maximum bag space and Pokemon storage? How many upgrades are needed to reach the limits?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go, bag space and Pokemon storage are limited. First, what are the starting limits?

More importantly, there are upgrades for 50 Bag Space and 50 Pokemon. How many of each of these upgrades these can be purchased?

With all upgrades purchased, what are the resulting limits?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The current maximum is **3000** for Pokémon storage, and **2500** for item storage.

---

Originally, it was 1000. As others have also, I fully upgraded mine. I can also confirm that the price stayed the the same for every upgrade purchased to the maximum.

Here is a screenshot of my storage at 1000 each, and the message I got after trying to buy another upgrade once the cap was reached:

[image: Your storage is fully upgraded]

Is it worth maxing Pokemon storage? It really does come down to this: for most people, this is NOT necessary. It simply fits the way I wanted to play Pokémon GO. I am not interested in having the highest CP Pokémon or battling Gyms for the time being. I simply enjoy playing "my way", I don't see the value of maxing out Pokémon Storage for 99.999% of players.

---

**Updates:**

- In June 2017, max capacity for items [was increased to 1500](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/878038226191233028).
- In May 2018, max capacity for items [was increased to 2000](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/996480700877504512).
- In July 2019, max capacity for Pokemon [was increased to 2500](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/1155908375630295045).
- In November 2019, max capacity [was increased](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/1197985622549573633) to 3000 for Pokémon and 2500 for items.

Comment: I understand maxing the item storage but can you explain your opinion why did you max out the Pokemon storage?

Comment: @Angelo If you buy pokemon storage upgrade you can save pokemon up until the next "event" where transfers might give 2 candy instead of the normal 1. (this was the case during Halloween).

Comment: As of May 2020, the storage maximum was increased to 3,000 for both the item bag and Pokemon

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** This answer is outdated.  Please refer to [@JustAHuman's updated answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276311/62235.).

---

The maximum is 1000 for item storage and 1000 for Pokemon storage.

Comment: Assuming the cost is the same for each upgrade (200), you'll need 5600 coins to do this, which is around $65

Comment: Doing the math from the previous answer I came up with starting limits of 300 for each. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @user154029 You start with 250 for each. Is there a source that 1000 is the max for these?

Comment: you start with 250 pokemon storage and 350 item storage

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:
As pointed out, the actual question is what are the maximums. They are both 1,000.
The starting sizes are:

- Items: 350
- Pokémon: 250

So at +50 per upgrade, the most you need to buy is:

- For the items: (1000-350)/50 = 13 upgrades
- For the Pokémon: (1000-250)/50 = 15 upgrades

To see the current size, you can view via:

Select the Pokéball menu button > Items

Select the Pokéball menu button > Pokémon

At the top it says e.g.

Items

354/350

Note that you can go over the limit - I think it is only Pokéstops that prevent you gaining items right now but haven't checked for sure. 
It might just be important events like levelling up that allow you to go over.

Comment: Great response, Rich. I can confirm that levels will give you everything if your bag is full. I wish I had screenshot it for you, but I hadn't read this at the time. When I became a 23, I had just filled my bag and had 1048/1000 items. I figure this is because the game didn't want to cheat me out of my level rewards. Pokestops, as you pointed out, will NEVER take me over the limit.

Comment: Pokestops can only take you over the limit if you are right under it. For example i you are currently at 349/350 and you can get 3 items from a pokestop and get 352/350. But leveling up and such can give you items even when you are already over the limit.

Answer (score 5):

The limit is 1k/1k

Once you hit 1k the store informs you there is no more upgrades for each

I'm maxed on both so this isn't random guessing

Answer (score 2):

You can buy upgrades in the store for your Bag and Pokémon storage until you can carry 1000 items and 1000 Pokémon. I am at the Max on both of them, and the store does not let you purchase more upgrades.