# What happens after reaching 99x items of a kind?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know it is possible to get over 99 Balls.

I have 99x Max-Potions and haven't found one since 30+ Pokéstops.
Which may answer my question or may be coincidence. I never recieved less than 3 items from a Pokéstop.


Imagine I keep 99 pieces of berries and each potion (don't mind the bag-limit ;) ) and I spin a Pokéstop.

Do I get only Pokéballs? Do I recieve only the items I can carry? Or will another "stack" of items be opened? Or do I have sheer bad luck with getting Max-Potions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What happens after 99? *100*. Seriously. I've had 100+ berries, and various potions.

So long as you have room in your bag it should be possible to get more*. I've gone a few dozen Pokestops without getting more Ultra Balls, and I have nowhere near 99 of those; they are just the rarest of the 3 Pokeball types. Max Potions, being the rarest of 4 would, I assume, have a lower drop rate than even Ultra Balls (rates may depend on your level).

*caveat: due to the nature of programming, it is possible that the item count would eventually [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). But given [bag limits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273331/30115), the amount of an item necessary to do so is likely beyond what is possible without otherwise breaking the game.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48730/discussion-on-answer-by-trent-hawkins-what-happens-after-reaching-99x-items-of-a).

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit at 99, at least for Ultra Balls. This must be just a co-incidence that you seem to have stopped receiving items when reaching 99.

[image: Source: Screenshot from my game]